# Proxy authentication with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, proxy-authentication

I am using the following code. I have removed the actual 'username' and 'password' and 'proxy_address' objects for privacy reasons.

```
auth = HTTPProxyAuth('username', 'password')
r = requests.get(hyperlink, proxies={'http': proxy_address, 'https': proxy_address}, 
auth=auth, timeout=5)
```

I get the following error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bafybeihpjhkeuiq3k6nqa3fkgeigeri7iebtrsuyuey5y6vy36n345xmbi.ipfs.dweb.link', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /45 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))
```

What should I do to resolve this issue? I have tried looking into the documentation for python Requests but I haven't been able to find a solution for my implementation. Thanks!